# passing Id from one ActionResult to another in mvc3 without sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to pass an Id from one ActionResult to another in mvc3 I tried using session ,but how to do without using sessions concept

I am using a Ajax based Views

My Actionresult 1

```
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
    Session["mId"] = Id;
    return View();
}
```

and i want to pass that here

```
public ActionResult B(int mid)
{
    mId =Convert.ToInt32(Session["mId"]);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just use a cookie?

Comment: main priority is to develop the application without using session

Comment: Try to include the information in the request

Answer (score 2):

I also try to avoid sessions where possible. A comment regarding your code you posted, please make sure that it indents properly. It is easy to read if it indents properly.

The `RedirectToAction` method redirects to the specified action method based on the parameters that you supplied.

Your 2 action methods could look like this:

```
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
     // Always check incoming parameters
     // Check that id is not zero or negative

     return RedirectToAction("B", new { mid = id });
}

public ActionResult B(int mid)
{
     // Check that mid is not zero or negative

     // Now you can do with mid what you need to do, for example:
     int myId = mid;

     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**Controller.RedirectToAction**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) Method

```
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
//Session["mId"] = Id;
return RedirectToAction("B",new {mid=id});
}
```

Comment: It would be `new {mid = id}`?